# How to create char array of predefined size while input at runtime?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to store `input1` `input2` `input3` in `char array` of given same size.

```
public static void evalCharArray(int size){

      System.out.println("please enter any three string not exceed than size"+size); 
         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         String input1=sc.nextLine();
         String input2=sc.nextLine();
         String input3=sc.nextLine();
        //what i need is-I want to store these input string in three separate charArray of same length(ie of int size)
  }
```

If i am using `input1.toCharArray()` `input2.toCharArray()` `input3.toCharArray()` these are giving me array of different size based on input.

Comment: input1, input2, and input3 in a single char array? or 3 separate char array with the same size?

Comment: these are separate arrays.

Comment: `please enter any three string not exceed than size` what does that mean?

Comment: What if the user enters a string more than `size` characters?

Comment: @NamanGala this size is the size  of char array since we have to put it into char array of length `size`.

Comment: @CoolGuy I will  manage this later depend on requirement like throwing exception etc.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians Can't you just create 3 char arrays of the given size, and copy the strings to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) method.

You can use this sample code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "work";
    char[] arr = new char[10];
    System.arraycopy(s.toCharArray(), 0, arr, 0, s.toCharArray().length );
    System.out.println(arr.length); // prints 10
    System.out.println(arr); // prints work
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Arrays.copyOf(T[], int)`.

```
 char[] input1=Arrays.copyOf(sc.nextLine().toCharArray(), size);
```

> Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with nulls (if
>   necessary) so the copy has the specified length.